# Crystal Report Cross tab - database driven sub column

Tags: database, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

I am facing a issue with how to make multiple sub column based on the data available in Crystal Reports. I have data in years with each quarter. So my columns header should be like `YEAR` from the database and each year will have sub columns for each quarter (like Q1, Q2, etc.). In the row field it should be each agency with the sum of each each year quarter wise. Finally it will show the total for each quarter.
Something like

```
YEAR       2008        2009        TOTAL 
          Q1 | Q2     Q1 | Q2     Q1 | Q2
Agency1  100 | 200   150 | 100   250 | 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `Year` and `Quarter` data with you in database.. below approach will be helpful.

1. Create a formula `Year` and take the year field from database

   ```
           tablename.Year
   ```
2. Create one more formula `Quarter`

   ```
              tablename.Quarter
   ```
3. Place the both formulas in column part in `Crosstab Expert`
4. Place agency in `rows` part and sunmmary of values in `Summarized Fields`